# VueJs / Laravel. Sum of Multiple arrays in different objects

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i use this code to display all persons i have.

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="person in persons">
</div>
```

//Each Person is an Object. in Each Object there are multiple objects(Money Given). i Need to Calculate the sum of total amount (Array) existing in those objects (All money given to each person)

//Like to say, all the credits relative to each Person.

I use to do that with Php, but how can i do that with computed ?

Vuejs code :

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
   persons:[],
},
methods: {
getPersons (),
},
```

Thanks you !

Here is a sample of persons. multiples objects, and inside each object, usercashfloats with multiple objects i need to calculate the amount . (Amount exist in each these objects) 
[image]

Comment: please provide a sample of `persons` data

Comment: Thank you sir, i add a picture for u, i want to calculate the sum of amount existing in all objects existing in usercashfloat

Comment: my bro could you expand one item in `usercashfloat`?

Comment: i provided an answer by assuming that each item in `usercashfloat` array has `amount` property

Comment: Yes, sir, in each object inside usercashfloat there is amount..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `computed` property should be like :

```
  computed:{
      personsWithAount(){

             const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.amount + currentValue.amount;
              return  this.persons.map((pers)=>{
                      let p=pers;
                      if(pers.usercashfloat.length==0){

                       p.totalAmount=0;
                       }else if(pers.usercashfloat.length==1){
                           p.totalAmount=pers.usercashfloat[0].amount;

                       }else{
                            p.totalAmount=pers.usercashfloat.reduce(reducer);
                       }
                     return p;
                     });


          }
       }
```

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function doc

and in your template you will have something like :

```
 <div class="col-md-3" v-for="person in personsWithAmount">
     {{person.totalAmount}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i got error during evaluation .. also, how i'm supposed to call total of each person in blade ?

Answer (score 2):

It could be like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="person in preparedPersons">
</div> 

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
   persons:[],
},
computed: {
   preparedPersons : function() {
      return this.persons.map(
         (p) => {
             return {
                   ...p, 
                   sumOfAmount: p.usercashfloat.reduce(
                       (acc, cur) => acc.amount + cur.amount
                   )
              };
          }
      )
   }
},
methods: {
getPersons (),
},
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i add a picture for u, i want to calculate the sum of amount existing in all objects existing in usercashfloat's objects

Comment: what  is structure of usercashfloat object ?

Comment: @yassinej I made changes to the answer so it should works for you fine

Comment: Thank you sir, i got error during evaluation .. also, how i'm supposed to call total of each person in blade ?

Comment: it will be like `<span>Amount is {{person.sumOfAmount}} </span>`